# How to allow trailing comma in function param list?

Tags: js2-mode

I have the following valid javascript with trailing comma in function parameters:

```js
const a = (...params) => console.log(params);
a(
  1,
  2,
  3,
);
```

But in `js2-mode` I see the error `missing ) after argument list`. Here is the screenshot of my emacs window - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFuBM.png

There is issue about that and PR for `js2-mode` on github:

- issue https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode/issues/403
- PR https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode/pull/410

As you can see on the screenshot I have the latest `js2-mode` with code from this PR.

Why do I still get this error? How can I fix or debug it?
Any help is appreciated

**Edit 0: How to reproduce this in clean environment?**

1. start clean emacs in docker using `docker run --rm -ti jare/emacs emacs -nw`
2. install js2-mode: `M-x package-install RET js2-mode`
3. create empty buffer, enable `M-x js2-mode`, type same text as in example
4. see the same error - https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYU6s.png

Comment: It works fine for me. Do you have `flycheck` enabled or any other linter?

Comment: Yes it was enabled at that time. Disabled it and edited code - still got this error

Comment: @caisah I've updated question with steps to reproduce this issue in a clean environment. Are you sure it works for you? Maybe you have `js2-mode` disabled at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appeared that this feature was not yet supported by js2-mode, but my PR [#454](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode/pull/454) was merged and should be available soon.

If you want to use it right now - the latest version is available on github. If you are using spacemacs - add this lines to .spacemacs file:

```
dotspacemacs-additional-packages 
  '((js2-mode :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "mooz/js2-mode")))
```